# ACF plot conflicts with the adf.test and KPSS test

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity

[image: acplot]

[image: pacfplot]

The acf plot exponentially decays after a lag spike at 2 and the pacf plot cuts off after lag 0. So, this indicates that the time series is stationary. But after doing adf.test and Kpss test, the result tells difference story.

```
    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  ltc.ts
Dickey-Fuller = 1.7982, Lag order = 3, p-value = 0.99
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

P-value of adf.test is 0.99 and I can not reject the null hypothesis : non-stationary

```
    KPSS Test for Level Stationarity

data:  ltc.ts
KPSS Level = 0.53558, Truncation lag parameter = 1,
p-value = 0.03365
```

P-value of KPSS test is 0.03 and I cant reject the null hypothesis : stationary.

What would I should do in this case? Should I follow the graph or test result. Please give me an advice!

Comment: It is ADF test, not ACF test. Got me confused in the beginning. You could edit this.

Comment: @RichardHardy I am sorry for the typo. I have edited it.